# javascript get date from datepicker than add days

Tags: javascript, php

I know that the question how to add days to date has been asked a lot. Tried those answers and it just does not work.
I have a date picker from I get the date in format d.m.Y and I get days to add in a php variable that I get from DB. And I want to display the added date in another input.
Getting the var and displaying in second input is no problem.

```js
var days = '2'; // <?php echo $days ?>;
days = parseInt(days);

function autoDatum() {
  var date_input = document.getElementById("date_input").value;
  var date = Date(date_input);
  var newdate = new Date(date);

  newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + days);

  var dd = newdate.getDate();
  var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = newdate.getFullYear();
  var someFormattedDate = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + y;

  document.getElementById('date_valute_input').value = someFormattedDate;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="date_input">date_input</label>
  <input id="date_input" type="text" value="16.03.2017">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="date_valute_input">date_valute_input</label>
  <input id="date_valute_input" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

I get only today's date + the days and not the selected date. I treed a lot of different code but only this one does not freeze.
Can some one have a idea how to parse the date proper?
In php and mysql working with dates is easy compared to javascript.

Comment: is the element `"date_input"` `<input type="date" ...` ? Or does it really return a numeric time (from UTC). If you want, you can use moment.js to aid you when working with date(times).

Comment: nope its <input type="text" /> the date is got as string d.m.Y.

Comment: If you got it as `d.m.Y.`, then you have to parse it yourself and use `new Date(year, month, day)` (where year, month and day got extracted from the string. - just split it ?) or use an external library that does the job for you.

Comment: @KarelG thank you... I don't use javascript very often. Now it works! I only had to do change month-1.

Answer (score 1):

As @KarelG said in the comments I had to parse the date I got form the input and now it works.

```
var days = <?php echo $days ?>;
days = parseInt(days);


function autoDatum() {
var date_input = document.getElementById("date_input").value;

var date = date_input.split(".");


var newdate = new Date(date [2], date [1]-1, date [0]);

newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + days);

var dd = newdate.getDate();
var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = newdate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + y;

document.getElementById( 'date_valute_input' ).value = someFormattedDate;
```

Comment: Just fyi, the reason to add + 1 is that in javascript, the month value starts at 0 (thus january = 0, february = 1, ... december = 11) which is confusing. But you at least did some effort. Have fun with _javascripting_

Answer (score 0):

use the moment library:
`n` - amount of days

```
var newDate = moment(date_input).add(n, 'days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to be working.
Isn't that what you expected?

```js
var days = '2'; // <?php echo $days ?>;
days = parseInt(days);

function autoDatum() {
  var date_input = document.getElementById("date_input").value.split('.');
  var date = new Date(date_input[2], date_input[1], date_input[0]);
  var newdate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + days);
  var dd = newdate.getDate();
  var mm = newdate.getMonth();
  var y = newdate.getFullYear();
  var someFormattedDate = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + y;

  document.getElementById('date_valute_input').value = someFormattedDate;
}

autoDatum();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="date_input">date_input</label>
  <input id="date_input" type="text" value="03.06.2015">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="date_valute_input">date_valute_input</label>
  <input id="date_valute_input" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but it allways took todays date. And the function isn't mine but I modified it from one I got from JSFidle. But forgot to save the link to give props to the author.

Comment: I've updated my answer and now it takes into consideration the date from the input field and adds 2 days to it

Comment: Your code is much cleaner than mine. But I'm allready using the one that KarelG helped me with.